# Vue select click on selector event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-mix, vue-select

I use [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) and I need to trigger the option open event, I tried:

`<v-select :filterable="false" onclick="this.customMethod('meow')" />`
but this not support vue methods.

Comment: Did you try @click="yourCB()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```html
<v-select :filterable="false" @search:focus="customMethod('meow')" />
```

If you want to see all events suported, [click here](https://vue-select.org/api/events.html#input).

For example, you want to dispatch event on element is clicked, you must to use `@search:focus` event.

If you want dispatch event on element is changed, you must to use `@input` event.

Answer (score 0):

If your method `customMethod()` is in the same code page (in METHOD part) than your line, call it without `this.` before method. And onclick is `@click="..."` or `v-on:click="..."`

So just `@click="myMethod"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@change='meow()'`

and include meow in your methods